# Xamarin Spinner itemSelected auto fires before selection

Tags: android, xamarin, spinner

I have a spinner, already setup an ItemSelected event which should fire whenever an item is selected.. My problem is the event is fired whenever the activity begins, before the user even selects an item.. How do I get around this?

Comment: 1st step: Edit your question and post some code :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by setting the SetSelection for my spinner and also setting the animation to false as follows : mySpinner.SetSelection(position,false) ..